# screen capture and syntax error using cv2.imread

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python and OPENCV and I need to write a python code that reads
an image.
I used some examples I've found online and I get some strange results.

Im running ubuntu12.04 and opencv2.4.9
First, when I run the file my mouse turn to cross wait for my input (4 clicks).
Second, I get a syntax massage that I can't find what is wrong in my code.
And the last one, when I look in the folder of the py file I see 2 new files:
 "cv2" -A screenshot of my first click and "np" - the other 3 screenshots (the other 3 clicks)

Here is the code:

### !/usr/bin/python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

### Read image

```
img = cv2.imread('clutter.jpg')

Yellow_MIN = np.array([20, 50, 45],np.uint8)
Yellow_MAX = np.array([30, 255, 255],np.uint8)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, Yellow_MIN, Yellow_MAX)
cv2.imwrite('output2.jpg', frame_threshed)
```

--end of code--

**The syntax error is** :

```
./color_find_et.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./color_find_et.py: line 9: `img = cv2.imread('clutter.jpg')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [Flags specifying the color type of a loaded image](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

> Use the function cv2.imread() to read an image. The image should be in the working directory or a full path of image should be given.
>
> > Second argument is a flag which specifies the way image should be
> >     read.
>
> ```
> cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag.
> cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Loads image in grayscale mode
> cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED : Loads image as such including alpha channel
> ```
>
> Note
>
> Instead of these three flags, you can simply pass integers 1, 0 or -1
>   respectively.

specifically your code needs to be:

```
 img = cv2.imread('clutter.jpg', 0)
```

Comment: Hi, 

It is no good still , I did what @GPPK advised and even did a shorter   code :'code'

<pre> <code> import numpy as np <br/>import cv2


img = cv2.imread('clutter.jpg', 0)

still getting for mouse clicks as input and screen capture images that I didn't wanted, after all it says :
./readimage.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./readimage.py: line 6: `img = cv2.imread('clutter.jpg', 0)'

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing "import cv2"
you have to write

"from cv2 import * "